# Loading content into Blazor TabControl

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I've created a TabControl following this and similar guides:

https://blazor-university.com/templating-components-with-renderfragements/creating-a-tabcontrol/

The relevant code on my test Tabs.razor page is:

```
<TabControl>
  <TabPage Text="Tab 1">
    <h1>The first tab</h1>
  </TabPage>
  <TabPage Text="Tab 2">
    <h1>The second tab</h1>
  </TabPage>
  <TabPage Text="Tab 3">
    <h1>The third tab</h1>
  </TabPage>
</TabControl>
```

The pages inside the tabs themselves will have a lot more content than just one sentence. All the tabbed examples I've found just have the tab contents like this, flat on the page. Is there some way to make the tab content more modular, possibly having it live in separate files? I'd want it all to load on the page initialization, I'd just like to not have a big monster .razor page with the contents of all the tabs.

I'm not sure if I need nested layouts here or what, or how the rendering would work (I'll need the tab contents to behave like top-level razor pages with functions and submit actions, etc...).

Pretty new to this, obviously, and haven't been able to find an answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 <TabPage Text="Tab 1">
    <MyFirstTabbedComponent />
  </TabPage>
```

and then develop MyFirstTabbedComponent.razor as a page/component.
enfin, you have already done something similar.

Comment: I have no idea why this works, but it does, thanks! Do you have a link to more documentation on this? I've checked both Blazor and ASP.NET and couldn't find an example similar to my use-case. Thanks again!

Comment: The use of Components is the corner stone of Blazor. You may have overlooked it in the intro's. But the TabControl is also build out of Components (ie the TabPages).

Comment: Why are you using templated componants ? can't you just hide/show the componant you want to use in each tab ?

Comment: This is the essence of Blazor: the use of named Components in lieu of html markup.